# Verification of proof : Show that if $\phi (x,y)$ is harmonic, then $\phi_{x} - i\phi_{y}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, partial-derivative

Please check if I did this proof right.

> Show that if $\phi (x,y)$ is harmonic, then $\phi_{x} - i\phi_{y}$ is analytic. ( You may assume that $\phi$ has continuous partial derivatives of all orders.)

$\underline {Proof}$:

Let $\phi$ be harmonic and $\phi$ has continuous partial derivatives.

Now if we consider $u =\phi$ and $v = \phi$, it is enough to show that $u$ and $v$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial v} = \phi_{xx} = -\phi_{yy} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \phi_{xy} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

So then $u = \phi_{x}$ and $v = \phi_{y}$, satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation and hence $\phi{x} - \phi{y}$ is analytic.

Comment: Yes this is right, it is enough since you can assume that this partial derivative are continuously differentiable,  so the function is holomorphic in a subset $D$ of $C$. Therefore it can be represented by a positive power series, in that subset.  Buy as Eric said "quite a few typos".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks good except that you have quite a few typos.  You presumably mean to say $u=\phi_x$ and $v=-\phi_y$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}$.  And at the end, you presumably mean $u+iv=\phi_x-i\phi_y$ rather than $\phi x-\phi y$.  You could also point out explicitly where you are using the fact that $\phi$ is harmonic, since this is kind of implicitly buried in one of your equations.

Comment: thank you sir! Will fix ASAP!